# Heroku PIL ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'

Tags: python, heroku, python-imaging-library

I am creating a Heroku app in which I am using `PIL` and from `PIL import Image`.

When I run `heroku local`, it returns `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'`. I have tried using Pillow instead of PIL, but it returns the same error. PIL and Pillow are both in my requirements.txt.

A link to my full github repo is: https://github.com/maivey/flower-image-classifier

Please help as I do not understand why it will not recognize PIL or Pillow

Comment: try ```pip install Pillow```. Make sure to run it from within a python virtualenv. You dont want to clutter your main python installation generally speaking.

Comment: 1. Provide the full error traceback. 2. `pip freeze` > provide the Pillow version youa re using.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to install them.
If you use anaconda: `conda install PIL`
If you use pip: `pip install PIL`

Thanks

Comment: Thank you. I have tried pip install PIL and pip install Pillow, that’s where I am confused what I could be doing wrong.